# @ComponentScan doesn't work in my Minecraft plugin

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a plugin for Minecraft server in which I use this SpringFramework. And I use JavaConfig + Annotations, but my project couldn't normally in runtime due to @ComponentScan.I discovered the fact that this is only in the Minecraft server plugin, but I could be wrong. Although in a normal Spring project everything is scanned normally

I have a directory like this: me.stordshally.testplugin

Main class (me.stordshally.testplugin.Main)

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

   private User user;

   @Override
   public void onEnable() {

       ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
       user = context.getBean(FacebookUser.class);
   }
}
```

JavaConfig (me.stordshally.testplugin.SpringConfig)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

Component (me.stordshally.testplugin.FacebookUser) (exists also User interafce in that directory)

```
@Component
public class FacebookUser implements User {

   @Override
   public String getNet() {
       return "Facebook";
   }
}
```

And at the moment context.getBean I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'me.stordshally.testplugin.FacebookUser' available
```

onEnable - starts when the server starts, consider it as an analog of psvm.

Why is this happening? How can I fix my ComponentScan?

Github for test: https://github.com/Prot-CN/SpringBug

Comment: Can you share the folder structure too.

Comment: Sure, but what kind the folder structure? Is it IDEA project?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, some more information would have helped, however, I do not know what the `src` package structure looks like but try explicitly providing base package like

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "me.stordshally.testplugin")
```

This tells spring explicitly where to look for potentials beans to create. Please make sure you provide the path under which all your beans are located.

If this doesn't work, it means for some reason your application is failing, try running your app in debug mode by setting log-level to debug. It will tell where the issue is. it's the best I can tell from the info provided, Hope this helps.